# Write an elliptic curve with coefficients only depending on its j-invariant

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let

$$E:y^2 = 4x^3-g_2 x - g_3$$

be an elliptic curve and

$$j=\frac{g_2^3}{g_2^3-27 g_3^2}$$

denote to its $j$-invariant. I want to transform $E$ to find $f$ and $g$ s.t.

$$E:y^2=4x^3-f(j)x-g(j).$$

I have no clue what *ansatz* I should take for $f$ and $g$, nor how to transform $E$. Who can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula is well known to the experts, which number I do not count myself among. Since none of them has answered, let me lay it out here:
$$
y^2= 4x^3 + \frac{3j}{1-j}x +\frac j{1-j}\,.
$$
And here’s how you derive it: from
$$
j = \frac{g_2^3}{g_2^3-27g_3^2} = \frac1{1-\frac{27g_3^2}{g_2^3}}
$$
you conclude
$$
\frac{27g_3^2}{g_2^3} = \frac{j-1}j\,.
$$
So you just adjust $g_2$ and $g_3$ so that they  satisfy this requirement. In particular, $g_2=3j/(j-1)$ and $g_3=j/(j-1)$ work.

Comment: Similarly, I considered $E:y^2=x^3-cx-c$ and $j=\frac{c}{c-27}$. This leads to $c=\frac{27j}{j-1}$.

Comment: And probably with less work than I expended trying to rediscover the formula.

Comment: Sorry, I just found this way before checking back to the thread. I will therefore mark your answer as the solution. Thanks! ;)